# Авторизироваться сразу к нескольким юзерам

Tags: php

Пишу админку, хочу входить из нее в учетку юзеров. Можно как-то реализовать так, чтобы я мог в разных вкладках быть под разными юзерами, но при этом не светить в урле идентификатор юзера / его куку? Тоесть одна вкладка - один юзер

Comment: В сессию добавить несколько пользователей

Answer (score 0):

Да,

в админке сделать кнопочку "авторизоваться", под тем пользователем под которым ты хочешь,

добавить в массив $_SESSION, ключ "USERS", а в него помещать ID пользователей под которыми ты хочешь сидеть, то есть когда откроешь новую вкладку, скрипт проверит есть ли в массиве $_SESSION["USERS"] ID пользователя, под которым ты хочешь сидеть, если он есть, тогда отобразишь страницу этого пользователя.

Ну и потом в админке сделать кнопку "выход", по нажатии на которую ты удалишь ID пользователя из массива $_SESSION["USERS"].

Ну а при отображении страницы, добавить скрипт проверку массива $_SESSION["USERS"], чтобы при открытии страницы он говорил, что можно это страницу отобразить как для этого пользователя или для этого, и выберешь для какого пользователя показать данную страницу.